# Pass jQuery array value on submit as hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On button press the following code will display a message with values collected from all checkboxes. But I want to pass these values (returned by function) as hidden input on submit.

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chb1" value="html" />HTML<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chb2" value="css" />CSS<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chb3" value="javascript" />JavaScript<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chb4" value="php" />php<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chb5" value="python" />Python<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chb6" value="net" />Net<br/>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="btntest" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
  var selchbox = [];        
  var inpfields = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;
   for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
  }
  return selchbox;
}


document.getElementById('btntest').onclick = function(){
  var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this.form);   
  alert(selchb);
}
//-->

</script>
```

Comment: Consider using an array for your checkbox names: `chb[]`

Comment: I've removed the part of your question where you ask for your code to be fixed - that's not how it works here. Would you edit your question to feature a specific question? What exactly are you stuck on? If you want to submit a form via AJAX, consider the Form plugin to jQuery.

Comment: @rybo111 the idea here is to use multiple checkbox with diffrent names...

Comment: @halfer NO I don't want Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen guys like you trying to code my router interface, so I'll help out.

1. give your form an id cause you'll need it later

   ```
   <form action="script.php" method="post" id="the_form">
   ```
2. add the hidden input in the form

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="values" id="values" value="" />
   ```
3. the button in the form matures to a real submit (amazing)

   ```
   <input type="submit" ...
   ```
4. your "getSelectedChbox()" function is amazing; don't change anything there, just wanted to give you congratulations for it, it's a great function
5. now, where it says `document.getElementById('btntest').onclick` - get rid of all that and add this code instead; this code will do the rest.

   ```
   document.getElementById('the_form').onsubmit = function(){
       var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this); 
       var values = selchb.join(', ');

       if(!values.length){
           alert('There was an error. You have to select some checkboxes. ');
           return false;
       }

       document.getElementById('values').value = values;
       if(!confirm(" Are you interested in submitting this form now? If not, click accordingly. "))
           return false;
   }
   ```

---

Or simply copy-paste this whole thing in a file called `script.php`:

```
<?php echo var_dump(isset($_POST['values']) ? $_POST['values'] : 'Submit first.'); ?>

<form action="script.php" method="post" id="the_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb1" value="html" />HTML<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb2" value="css" />CSS<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb3" value="javascript" />JavaScript<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb4" value="php" />php<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb5" value="python" />Python<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chb6" value="net" />Net<br/>

    <input type="hidden" name="values" id="values" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Click" id="btntest" />

</form>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function getSelectedChbox(frm) {
    var selchbox = [];        
    var inpfields = frm.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;
    for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {
        if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) 
            selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);
    }
    return selchbox;
}


document.getElementById('the_form').onsubmit = function(){
    var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this); 
    var values = selchb.join(', ');

    if(!values.length){
        alert('There was an error. You have to select some checkboxes. ');
        return false;
    }

    document.getElementById('values').value = values;
    if(!confirm(" Are you interested in submitting this form now? If not, click accordingly. "))
        return false;
}
//-->

</script>
```

Have fun.

Comment: Many thanks though it serves the purpose but can't it be more simpler like this 
<form onsubmit="myFunction()"> ??? 
if yes pls tell me how

Comment: I was trying to do this actually but its not working 
<form action="script.php" method="post" onsubmit="getchecks()">


function getcheks(){

    var selchb = getSelectedChbox(this); 
    var values = selchb.join(', ');
document.getElementById('values').value = values;
}

Comment: @khurram4m normally it should work; put some alerts for example `<form onsubmit="alert(getSelectedChbox(this))">` and see what it returns. And don't forget to select some checkboxes first.